# No qualifying bean, annotated with @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration, autowired

I use @ConfigurationProperties for configurating properties:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ConfigurationProperties("kafka")
public class KafkaConnectionSettings {
     private String bootstrapAddress = "dataflow-kafka:9092";
{
```

And trying to autowire it in other configuration-class. For example:

```
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
public class KafkaProducerConfig {
    private KafkaConnectionSettings kafkaSettings;

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
    configProps.put(
       ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,kafkaSettings.getBootstrapAddress());
   }
}
```

But I receive the following exeption:

```
No qualifying bean of type 'com.app.config.kafka.KafkaConnectionSettings' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: kafkaConnectionSettings,kafka-com.app.config.kafka.KafkaConnectionSettings
```

Its a "little" strange, considering that in "com.app.config"-package I have a similar config:

```
 @Getter
 @Setter
 @ConfigurationProperties("app")
public class FileSettings {
}
```

and this last authowired successfully in classes, annotated with @Service

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, you have 2 spring beans with same return type. You can use a @Qualifier on expected one and on a later step, you can remove or merge unexpected one, removing qualifier annotation.

Comment: Gweltaz Niquel, thank you for your attempt. But my question was not quite clear. I answered on my question, by clarifying, that I use test context.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is solved. I forgot to add KafkaConnectionSettings.class in @EnableConfigurationProperties at my testclass

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@EnableConfigurationProperties({FileSettings.class, KafkaConnectionSettings.class})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class AppTest {
```

Sorry for not quite clear question.